# JavaScript and removeChild( ) magic

Tags: javascript, dom

Why does this work? How does it know which item to delete without specifying which item? JavaScript magic?

```
let addButtton = document.getElementById('addButton');
let body = document.querySelector("body");


addButton.onclick = function addToList() {
    let taskName = document.getElementById("AddToList").value;
    let toDoList = document.createElement("input");
    toDoList.setAttribute("type", "checkbox");
    toDoList.id = "task";
    body.appendChild(toDoList);
    let deleteButton = document.createElement("button");
    deleteButton.innerHTML = "Delete";
    let label = document.createElement("label");
    label.setAttribute("for", ("task"));
    label.innerHTML = taskName;
    body.appendChild(label);
    body.appendChild(deleteButton);

    deleteButton.onclick = function deleteTask() {
        body.removeChild(label);
        body.removeChild(toDoList);
        body.removeChild(buttonDel);
        body.removeChild(breakLn);
    }
}
```

Comment: The item is specified by reference. For example, `label` is an html element. When you do `body.removeChild (label)`, you delete the associated html element.

Comment: thanks! But what if there are multiple items (labels) in the list? How is only one deleted?

Comment: All created `label` are scoped, So all `label` have unique reference

Answer (score 0):

When you are creating the item `let label = document.createElement("label");` inside `label` variable, it keeps the reference inside of it. When you pass as parameter `body.removeChild(label);`, remove him entirely from DOM.

Comment: makes sense.. but what if we've created multiple labels (items). How does the delete button target that specific label?

Comment: Because of your declaration, the `let` type says that that variable exists inside that context. Your delete is inside the `onclick` context.